# Relationship between angle of vector with corresponding projections on orthogonal subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^N$, and $H$ a non-trivial subspace (i.e. $H\neq\{0\}$ nor $H\neq\mathbb{R}^N$), and denote by $H^\perp$ its orthogonal complement.

Furthermore denote by $p_{H}(v)$ ($p_{H^\perp}(v)$) the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $H$ ($H^\perp$).

Is it always true that the sum of the angles between $v$ and each projection is always $\frac{\pi}{2}$? In other words is $$\theta_{vp_{H^\perp}(v)} + \theta_{vp_{H}(v)} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

where $\theta_{ab}$ denotes the angle between vector $a$ and vector $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depend on which scalar product you have on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and which vector you are considering. If it is the standard scalar product the answer is yes if $v\notin H$ and $v\notin H^\perp$ because the projection to the other factor is the $0-$vector , but your statement is not true in general.

Comment: Is there an elegant proof for this?

Comment: You don't need proof but counterexample. Try do some counterexample to understand why your claim is false.

Comment: I meant when all your conditions are satisfied and when the scalar product is the usual one